# ASP.NET - MVC 4 using a variable from a controller to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller like so:

```
public class PreviewController : Controller
{
    // GET: Preview
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string name = Request.Form["name"];
        string rendering = Request.Form["rendering"];

        var information = new InformationClass();
        information.name = name;
        information.rendering = rendering;

        return View(information);
    }
}
```

and in the view, I am trying to the information.name like so:

```
@ViewBag.information.name
```

I also tried just:

```
@information.name
```

but got the same error for both:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the view just type

```
@Model.name
```

Since InformationClass is your model you just call its properties from the view using **@Model**

Answer (score 6):

You must use `@Model.name` in view. Not `@ViewBag.information.name`. Also in top of your view you must define something like this:

```
@model Mynamespace.InformationClass
```

And it would be better to use MVC's model binding feature. Therefore change your action method like this:

```
public class PreviewController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost] // it seems you are using post method
    public ActionResult Index(string name, string rendering)
    {
        var information = new InformationClass();
        information.name = name;
        information.rendering = rendering;

        return View(information);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `ViewBag.InformationName` in your action:

```
ViewBag.InformationName = name;
```

And then in your view you could reference it:

```
@ViewBag.InformationName
```

Or if you're trying to work with the model data in the view, you'd reference it through this:

```
@Model.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add that sample to your view file

```
   @model Your.Namespace.InformationClass
```

That line is responsible for defining your model type. And after that you can just use:

```
   @Model.name;
```